# What would life be if humans had a healing factor?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, humans, alternate-history, life

The main premise is that since homo sapiens evolved, humanity has possessed a healing factor similar to wolverine, but lesser.
How would modern-day life be different?

Comment: But we have healing factor. We can deal with poisons (which we consume for fun), we can deal with tissue lost (to some extent but we use this ability to make pictures on ourself), we use our healing factor to make ourselfs bigger, faster, more agile.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking something like surviving getting stabbed in the belly with a sword and healing in an hour or so. Can you do that?

Comment: Welcome to World Building SE, CodeDoge.  You can improve the quality of your answers if you define your terms directly in your question, instead of relying solely on references known to consumers of comic book media (movies/graphic novels/etc). Consider editing your question as people add comments requesting supplemental information so your question is always improving.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer.  It's unclear how much 'lesser" of a healing factor there is, and "how would modern-day life be different" is extremely open ended

Comment: @CodeDoge - Healing a sword-stab in an hour or so would only matter because *we* can't, if we could it would be normal to the species - the whole scale of healing, incapacitation time, injury level would be to them normal as our current healing factor is to *us*, which heals, say, a papercut in an hour or so.  That version would simply not fight with swords just like we don't fight with papercuts, but really life overall wouldn't be different *to them* just like our healing factor isn't different *to us* - and not much different to us, reading about it, once we get a sense of scale.

Answer (score 3):

Human healing have 4 stages:

1. Hemostasis
2. Inflammation
3. Proliferation
4. Remodeling

Fast healing means all stages are very short and happen instatly. I won't get into repercussions of that. But in the third stage, Prolifration, mesenchymal cells are, well, proliferating and migrating to the wound to repair it. Now, this is what make the biggest problem. Having mesenchymal cells in the amount to heal wounds fast means they are always present in the body. Which means human goes through constant, very fast, healing.
With all 4 stages.

So humans are in constant pain becuse they are always inflamated. You might think "well yes, then we evolve to not feel pain". Which is counter productive from evolutionary point of reason. We feel pain to remove stimulus so we are no longer hurt/damaged. If you put finger into lava you have onyl fingertip to repair. If you don't feel pain you don't know where to stop inserting yourself into molten rocks.

But back to influence on human development.
In the Maslow piramid of need we remove the need for safety. We don't fear wild animals, cold, we lose sense of danger (so we don't feel anxiety). Which lead to no need for building shelters and living in communities for better protection. Which lead to less frequent sexual encounters.
Less human per square meter means less society frictions and humans interactions that could lead to quarels (and wars). Less fighting means no need to develop things to better kills others (because it's already hard as hell) and less need for protection.

Answering question

> How would modern-day life be different?

There would be no "modern-day life" as there would be no need for humanity to go past hunters-gatherers stage.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wars would be much more devastating, you have to defeat somehow those enemy soldiers.
2. There would be much bigger population, child mortality would be dropped almost to 0. Also people would not die that much from other cases.
3. We would have that developed medicine because nobody would need it.
4. Much more genetic mutation's, coz weaker units wouldn't die
5. Society might be much less trustful, after all you cant stop that easily one bad guy with just few bullets or cuts.
6. There would be no more extreme sports, or it would become extremely extreme.
7. We would live every everywhere on planet.
8. Slavery probably would be much bigger thing, because your slave wouldn't die after whipping or extreme workload.

Aaaand some more, I guess I'll edit when with some new ideas that will come to my mind.

Comment: 8 different answers, and more to come when you have idea. In other words, why should I not answer too broad questions?